# How to calculate average of values without including the last value (sql)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table. I partition it by the id and want to calculate average of the  values previous to the current, without including the current value. Here is a sample table:

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | Value |    Date    |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 |    51 | 2020-11-26 |
|  1 |    45 | 2020-11-25 |
|  1 |    47 | 2020-11-24 |
|  2 |    32 | 2020-11-26 |
|  2 |    51 | 2020-11-25 |
|  2 |    45 | 2020-11-24 |
|  3 |    47 | 2020-11-26 |
|  3 |    32 | 2020-11-25 |
|  3 |    35 | 2020-11-24 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

In this case, it means calculating the average of values for dates BEFORE 2020-11-26. This is the expected result

```
+----+-------+
| id | Value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    46 |
|  2 |    48 |
|  3 |  33.5 |
+----+-------+
```

I have calculated it using `ROWS N PRECEDING` but it appears that this way I average N preceding + last row, and I want to exclude the last row (which is the most recent date in my case).
Here is my query:

```
SELECT ID, 
  (avg(Value) OVER(
      PARTITION BY ID
      ORDER BY Date
      ROWS 9 PRECEDING )) as avg9
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then define your window in full using both the start and ends with `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT ID,
       (AVG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS avg9
FROM t1;
```

Comment: This could not be simpler... And I was just suffering for the last 30 minutes.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just filter:

```
select id, avg(value)
from t1
where date < '2020-11-26'
group by id;
```

If you want the date to be flexible -- say the most recent value for each date, then:

```
select id, avg(value)
from (select t1.*,
             max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t1
     ) t1
where date < max_date
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a row_number() over (Partition by id ORDER BY [Date] DESC). This will give a rank = 1 to the row with latest date. Wrap it within a CTE and then calculate avg for each partition where RANK > 1. Please check syntax.

```
;with a as
(
select id, value, Date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date 
desc) as RN
)
select id, avg(Value) from a group by id where r.RN > 1
```